# Is it possible to save and restore libtask coroutines?

Tags: task, coroutine

I want to be able to suspend libtask coroutines to disk and then restore them again under a different process so they can continue where they left off.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.  Coroutine state is tied to the running process's execution state, open file descriptors, etc.  It's actually a very difficult problem to solve in the general case, see this page on Wikipedia for a discussion:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing

The approach you could take is to carefully define your coroutine's state and determine what information you'd need to store in order to reconstruct it.  Then, you'd make the coroutine able to resume given that information.

Dragonfly BSD has the ability to suspend tasks and later resume them, but that's the only general solution I've heard of, save for VM image-based systems like Smalltalk and Squeak.